MLE in stochastically increasing parametric family
Let $X$ have cumulative density function $F_{\theta}$, suppose this family is stochastically increasing in $\theta$, that is, for $\theta_1<\theta_2$, $F(x;\theta_2) \le F(x;\theta_1)$.
We have one data point, $X$. I believe that the MLE for $\theta$ must be a non-decreasing function of $X$. Intuitively, this should be true, because for a larger of $\theta$, $X$ will tend to be bigger, so a larger value of $X$ is likely from a larger value of $\theta$ as well. However, I cannot prove this. I find it quite difficult to translate the definition of stochastically increasing into a statement about likelihoods.

It cannot be proved for it is not true unless additional assumptions are taken.

Please give me a counter example. Would it be true if we assume the monotone likelihood property?

Counterexample:
Imagine the pmf's of the following three distributions with increasing stochastic dominance for increasing $\theta$
               x
      | 0    1    2    3
 -----+-----------------
    1 | 1    0    0    0
θ   2 | 0.5  0    0.5  0
    3 | 0    0.5  0    0.5 

If you observe $x=1$ then $\hat{\theta} = 3$, if you observe $x=2$ then $\hat{\theta} = 2$.
Therefore, a higher observed value, doesn't necessarily lead to a higher a higher estimate.

related: Should we really search for the model for which the probability of the data is maximal?

Answer to comments

This is not a very satisfactory example because of the discreteness of the parameter space.

For a distribution with a continuous parameterisation you can consider an intepolation with a parameter space $\theta \in [1,3]$
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{3-\theta}{2} &&&\quad \text{if $x = 0$} \\
&&\frac{\theta-2}{2} \cdot \mathbb{I}_{\theta\geq2} &\quad \text{if $x = 1$} \\
\frac{\theta-1}{2} \cdot \mathbb{I}_{\theta < 2} &+ &\frac{3-\theta}{2} \cdot \mathbb{I}_{\theta \geq 2} &\quad \text{if $x = 2$}  \\
&&\frac{\theta-2}{2} \cdot \mathbb{I}_{\theta \geq 2} &\quad \text{if $x = 3$}  \\
\end{cases}$$
and for a distribution with a continuous variable you can consider compounding the distribution above with a continuous variable (turning the point masses into density distributions).

Would it be true if we assume the monotone likelihood property?

Yes, if the monotone property is always the same direction for every $\theta_1>\theta_2$.
Let
$$\text{if}\quad  \theta_1 > \theta_2 \land x > y \quad \text{then}\quad \frac{f_{\theta_1}(x)}{f_{\theta_2}(x)} \geq  \frac{f_{\theta_1}(y)}{f_{\theta_2}(y)}$$
Now consider the value $\theta_1$ to be the mle for $y$, ie $\hat{\theta} = \theta_1$ if the observation is $y$, then
$$ \frac{f_{\theta_1}(x)}{f_{\theta_2}(x)} \geq  \frac{f_{\theta_1}(y)}{f_{\theta_2}(y)} > 1.$$
So the value $\hat{\theta} = \theta_2$ cannot be an MLE for $x$ because $$\frac{f_{\theta_2}(x)}{f_{\theta_1}(x)} < 1.$$

Thank you. What if we also assume the monotone likelihood property?

This is not a very satisfactory example because of the discreteness of the parameter space.  There exist nice continuous-parameter examples of continuous distributions; plotting them is instructive.

@Whuber it doesn't change the principle when we change the parameter space into a continuous distribution. We could interpolate between the three points, and the result is the same.

I am unconvinced by your MLR argument, because those inequalities do not immediately imply your conclusion that the mle "will be smaller." // It also is not immediately clear what you are interpolating or why that would work, because (a) linear interpolation of the probabilities will not necessarily create a valid density and (b) linear interpolation of the CDF potentially makes the density undefined at the original discrete support.

@whuber the subscripts have been a bit scrambled in that comment. Let
$$\text{if}\quad  \theta_1 > \theta_2 \land x > y \quad \text{then}\quad \frac{f_{\theta_1}(x)}{f_{\theta_2}(x)} \geq  \frac{f_{\theta_1}(y)}{f_{\theta_2}(y)}$$
Now consider $\theta_1$ to be the mle for $y$, then
$$ \frac{f_{\theta_1}(x)}{f_{\theta_2}(x)} \geq  \frac{f_{\theta_1}(y)}{f_{\theta_2}(y)} > 1$$
So $\theta_2$ cannot be a MLE for $x$ because $$\frac{f_{\theta_2}(x)}{f_{\theta_1}(x)} < 1$$

@SextusEmpiricus, not on the content of the answer, but perhaps add a hat to theta when you are talking about it as an estimator.

@User1865345 I made an edit in the final paragraph, is that what you meant?

It took me time to understand your mlr argument. But now that I have, I think you can add that since $\theta_2$ was arbitrary and smaller than $\theta_1, $ mle corresponding to the observation $x$ would be of (equal or) higher value than $\theta_1$ proving the fact that mle is indeed a nondecreasing function of $x, $ that is, $x<y \implies \hat \theta(x) <\hat\theta(y)$ and mlr in fact guaranteeing that the cdfs are stochastically increasing in $\theta$ (which is not directly needed here to prove the order preservation) @SextusEmpiricus.

@User1865345 If stochastic dominance for distributions with a larger parameter $\theta$ would imply $x<y \implies \hat \theta(x) <\hat\theta(y)$ (as supposed in the OP), then indeed as a consequence we have that $\hat\theta(x)|\theta_1$ dominates $\hat\theta(x)|\theta_2$. And showing that the latter is false is a counterexample as well.
